# UIButtonに吹き出しを付けることはできますか？

Tags: swift

お世話になっております。
質問は表題の通りです。
設置したUIButtonをタップした時、吹き出しを表示することはできますか？
iPhoneのUSキーボードのアルファベットをタップした時に、そのキーの文字が吹き出しで出てきますよね？（下記）
それをUIButtonで表示する方法があればご教授いただけますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIButton自体に吹き出しをつける処理は無いので、UIButtonがタップされた処理の中で画像、もしくはViewをUIButtonの位置に表示させる必要があります

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございました。チャレンジしてみます。